# How do I revert a commit with gitpython?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

For a python script I'm writing (using Python 2.7 on Windows 7) I should be able to modify a branch with a given commit, that is adding it (cherry pick) if the commit is missing, or reverting it if it's already present.

Apparently revert has not been wrapped in gitpython's Repo class, so I tried to [use Git directly](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly) with:

```
repo.git.revert(reference)
```

where `reference` is one of the commits returned by `repo.iter_commits("master")`

What happens is that the script locks on that command and becomes idle; I then have to kill the command prompt window.
If I go in the working directory and explore the repository, I can see (with `git diff`) that after the execution, the changes have been applied even tho' no new commit is visibile if I `git log`.

Any ideas about if and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know how `gitpython` works, but a wild guess is that it got stuck in a conflicted state -- `git revert` takes the changes that a given commit introduces, reverses them and then tries to apply them. If the reversed diff cannot be applied cleanly, there will be a conflict.

Comment: Thanks jsageryd for the answer. The problem was actually that the command was being executed as if it was run from a terminal, hence waiting for me to edit the commit message!

Comment: Ah. This makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the mistery by trying to `git commit` the applied changes manually. Git complained about a swap file in the working directory.

So, the problem was that the command was being executed as if it was run from a terminal, hence waiting for me to somehow edit the commit message! So I needed to run the `revert` command with the `no-edit` option.

I changed the method invocation to:

```
repo.git.revert(reference.hexsha, no_edit = True)
```

(notice that `gitpython` requires the underscore as a separator. Also, using explicitly the `hexsha` property is not required, since `reference` would be converted to its `str()` representation anyway.)

It seems to work.

Comment: It seems repo.git.revert() is no longer available

Comment: When a method is not implemented, it is executed as a git command thanks to python "magic methods": https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly